# How can I find a sequence from $l^p\setminus l^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, lp-spaces

I am trying to find out how to find this sequence

Find a sequence $x$ which is in $l^p$ with $p>1$ but $x \not\in l^1$

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Consider the convergence of
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}. $$